# Changing the scoring function in Neo4j

Tags: indexing, neo4j, lucene, scoring

I've developed a website that has a search facility that utilises Neo4j's full text search feature.

In order to build my index, I used the following cypher command:

`CALL db.index.fulltext.createNodeIndex(“ArticlesIndex”, [“Article”], [“title", “abstract”])`

I was wondering if there was any way to configure the scoring metric for this index? I believe Neo4j currently uses [VSM](https://lucene.apache.org/core/3_5_0/api/core/org/apache/lucene/search/Similarity.html) but I'm hoping to switch it to [BM25](https://lucene.apache.org/core/7_0_1/core/org/apache/lucene/search/similarities/BM25Similarity.html).

I've checked the [Neo4j Docs](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/reference/procedures/)- it mentions an optional 3rd argument `config` for `createNodeIndex()` but this only seems to have 2 supported options, neither of which override the default scoring metric.

I'm not exactly proficient with neo4j so any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot change the scoring function. Actually there isn't much you can configure except the analysers.